# How can I deactivate Find my iPhone's Erase iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

My iPhone 4s has been stolen and I have activated "Erase iPhone" through the iCloud, but I've found out that this disables Find My iPhone too.

How can I disable "Erase iPhone" to avoid deactivation of Find My Iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a way for you to withdraw an erase command from iCloud. Theoretically, if it hasn't been withdrawn, an engineer for Apple *could* go in and remove it from the queue assuming:

1. They could verify you were really you
2. You figured out how to convince them to do this

As for whether you can still track the device after an erase is sent, that depends on the version of iOS on the device.

If you have iOS 7 or later - the erase action does not stop tracking or remove the activation lock preventing a thief or someone who finds / buys it from being able to use the device. It will still show your lock message and **you can still track the device. Problem solved!**

If you are on iOS 6 or earlier, you are correct that you will have lost the chance to track the device once it connects and receives the wipe command. If it ever connects to Apple's servers, the wipe will happen and the device will be erased and you should get an email if/when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I recently misplaced my MacBook Pro and used iCloud to locate which didn't help because it was off. Anyhow I used iCloud to erase. Shortly thereafter I was given back my MacBook and couldn't figure out how to stop or cancel the erase.

After much research I followed some very simple directions.

1. Purchased an external hard drive to back up my MacBook.
2. Turned of the WiFi in the house.
3. Went into all the Apple devices and removed the MacBook from the device list.
4. Signed out of "Find My Device" on all devices.
5. Turned on the MacBook and turned off the WiFi and did a back up of the MacBook's hard drive onto the external hard drive.
6. Turned on the WiFi on the MacBook and kept my fingers crossed.

It did not erase my macbook. Whew that was simple too.

Answer (score 0):

As per apple's instructions, if after the erase command has been sent you remove the device from your find my phone list of devices all pending commands (including remote erase command)are removed.

Check this page 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201472
it states;

If your missing device is off or offline, you can still put it in Lost Mode, lock it, or remotely erase it. The next time your device is online, these actions will take effect. **If you remove the device from your account while it's offline, any pending actions for the device will be cancelled.**

Answer (score -1):

I have an iphone 4 (IOS 7) and recently I accidently erased my phone on Find My Iphone from my pc (my phone was not lost) so when my phone finished from the process of "erasing" my phone opened again and it said "Hello" in front like a new iphone would so I kept on filling up the info and then there was a part where it said that I can restore my previous phone info using Itunes or Icloud, I used Itunes to restore my phone and you should also fill in your Apple ID and password. It then take quite a while until its done but when its finished my phone came back almost like it was except that my apps were deleted

Comment: Apps would be also reinstalled with iCloud data it had if you activated iCloud backup(you are asked about it in activation wizard and can change that setting after)